# Universal Linking not showing app selection menu in case of multiple apps pointing to same domain

Tags: ios, iphone, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

We have multiple flavors of our app which is pointing to the exactly same server; We can’t differentiate different apps from looking into the domain urls and their paths.

For Example, from any of the app, if we request **Forgot your Password** then the link received for **Reset Password** in email will be same for both the apps. So, if we tap on the link, it will open any of the app instead of asking user which app should be open by showing menu with all available apps. Actually its opening the first app which **Bundle ID** matches in **apple-app-site-association** file placed on server.

**Domain Registration in App Associated Domains section:** applinks:example.com

**Content in apple-app-site-association file placed at server:**

```
{
   "applinks": {
      "apps": [

      ],
      "details": [{
            "appID": "XXXXXXXXXX.com.example.FirstApp",
            "paths": [
               "NOT /sample/activate/*",
               "*"
            ]
         },
         {
            "appID": "XXXXXXXXXX.com.example.SecondApp",
            "paths": [
               "NOT /sample/activate/*",
               "*"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Actual Behavior:**
If both apps installed on device, by taping on link in browser, it will open FirstApp **OR** SecondApp

**Expected Behavior:**
If both apps installed on device, then by taping on link, iOS should give choice to user, which app he/she wants to open.

Any way to achieve expected behavior with above explained scenario?

Comment: This is a limitation on iOS. iOS platform does not give the option to choose from apps. It will open the link with the option they think suits best and there is not way around it.

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh Any alternate or workaround? Its necessary to handle in my case. Correct app should open.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple's documentation on AASA files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html), the device will always register the first app with a matching URL.

> The value of the details key is an array of dictionaries, one dictionary per app that your website supports. The order of the dictionaries in the array determines the order the system follows when looking for a match, so you can specify an app to handle a particular part of your website.

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a work around since this occurs at the OS level of the device. Your best bet is to distinguish the URLs somehow. Sorry, I know that's probably not the answer you wanted to hear.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Yes its the limitation. I want any way to achieve this behavior instead of changing in urls. Do you know whats the behavior of branch.io in this case?

Comment: Branch's links leverages universal links so its behavior will be the same in this case :(

Comment: No changes in later 2019? According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links - yes, no changes.

Comment: The documentation has been removed as of late 2020. Is this technique still valid?